# Special advantage of `ddply` over `stats::ave`?

Tags: r, plyr

Using this data set (InsectSprays).

```
> d <- InsectSprays
> str(d)
'data.frame':   72 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ count: num  10 7 20 14 14 12 10 23 17 20 ...
 $ spray: Factor w/ 6 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ total: num  174 174 174 174 174 174 174 174 174 174 ...
```

For each factor individually  (i.e. spray type), how can the total number of counts be added to every observation?
I.e. we want

```
> head(d)
  count spray total
1    10     A   174
2     7     A   174
3    20     A   174
4    14     A   174
5    14     A   174
6    12     A   174
```

In some lecture, the use of `ddply` is suggested:

```
> head(ddply(d, .(spray), summarize, sum=ave(count, FUN=sum)))
  spray sum
1     A 174
2     A 174
3     A 174
4     A 174
5     A 174
6     A 174
```

Is there a specific advantage of this command over just using `ave` by itself?

```
> d$total <- ave(d$count, d$spray, FUN=sum)
> head(d)
  count spray total
1    10     A   174
2     7     A   174
3    20     A   174
4    14     A   174
5    14     A   174
6    12     A   174
```

I'm not saying `ddply` has no merit, but in this particular example, I feel I don't see the point of using it.

Is there a specific advantage of the `ddply` application here?

Comment: You could get similar result with `ddply(d, .(spray), mutate, total=sum(count))`

Comment: I think most advocates of `plyr` find the syntax clearer - especially its flexibility whereas in base R you may need to alternate using `ave`, `tapply` and `aggregate`. *However* at this point `dplyr` has essentially supplanted `plyr::ddply`, and it comes with substantial speed advantages as well as consistent syntax.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea...

```
> library("microbenchmark")
> microbenchmark(ddply(d, .(spray), summarize, sum=ave(count, FUN=sum)), d$total <- ave(d$count, d$spray, FUN=sum))
Unit: microseconds
                                                       expr      min        lq    median        uq       max neval
 ddply(d, .(spray), summarize, sum = ave(count, FUN = sum)) 4262.996 4418.8750 4504.3195 4620.7480 10167.530   100
                d$total <- ave(d$count, d$spray, FUN = sum)  222.080  232.2795  249.2145  267.8815   620.822   100
```

Comment: Ok, probably the instructor just wanted to appear impressive.